# SQL Query Maintained Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with columns

`customer ID, Account ID, Transaction Date, balance`

I would like to query the table and get all the accounts that maintained `$500` in any given month and for the entire month. if the account maintained a balance for `$500` for the entire month except for one day, that would disqualify it.

How do I query the table?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be great here

Comment: And showing what you tried so far is also kind of the norm around here.

Comment: So you want all accounts that *don't* have that ballance grouped by month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `all` the values of balance and compare them to 500:

```
DECLARE @mydate datetime = '2018-12-01';

select 
  distinct accountid 
from 
  tablename t
where
  month(t.transactiondate) = month(@mydate) 
  and 
  year(t.transactiondate) = year(@mydate)
  and
  500 <= all (
    select 
      tablename.balance 
    from tablename 
    where
      tablename.accountid = t.accountid
      and 
      month(tablename.transactiondate) = month(@mydate) 
      and 
      year(tablename.transactiondate) = year(@mydate)
  )
union
select t.accountid from (
  select 
    accountid, 
    max(transactiondate) maxtransactiondate 
  from tablename t
  where
    not exists (
      select 
        1 
      from tablename 
      where
        tablename.accountid = t.accountid
        and 
        month(tablename.transactiondate) = month(@mydate) 
        and 
        year(tablename.transactiondate) = year(@mydate)
    )
    and
    transactiondate < @mydate
  group by accountid) t
where (
  select tablename.balance 
  from 
    tablename
  where 
    tablename.accountid = t.accountid
    and
    tablename.transactiondate = t.maxtransactiondate
) >= 500
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=edab4aa1815b6659f385b2738343b6e3).

Comment: I wonder what happens if there aren't any transactions in the month but previous month(s) closing balance was 500

Answer (score 0):

First of all your table is filled with too many information. I suggest you create three tables, one for customers, one for accounts and one for transactions:

```
create table tblCustomers
(
    CustomerID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerFirstName nvarchar(50),
    CustomerLastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ...
)

create table tblAccounts
(
    AccountID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AccountNo nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    AccountBalance decimal NOT NULL,
    ...
)

create table tblTransactions
(
    TransactionID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TransactionFrom int NOT NULL,
    TransactionTo int NOT NULL,
    TransactionDateTime datetime NOT NULL,
    TransactionAmount int NOT NULL
)
```

This way you can actually book back and forth. 
Now you need an extra table where you can actually store the balance of each account for each day:

```
create table tblAccountHistory
(
    AccountHistoryID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AccountFSID int NOT NULL,
    Balance decimal NOT NULL,
    SnapshotDate datetime NOT NULL,
    IsBelow bit NOT NULL
)
```

You're going to have to write the balances down each and every day though.
This could look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertAccountBalances

AS   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    insert into dbo.tblAccountHistory (AccountFSID, Balance, SnapshotDate, IsBelow)
    Select AccountID, AccountBalance, GETDATE(), 0
    From 
    dbo.tblAccounts

    update dbo.tblAccountHistory
    set
    IsBelow = 1
    where Balance <= 499.99
GO
```

Just run that daily with the Task Scheduler from Windows and Powershell.

Then you can create your query to get all those values

```
Select ac.AccountID, ac.AccountNo, Count(ah.IsBelow)
From dbo.tblAccounts ac
inner join
dbo.tblAccountHistory ah on ac.AccountID = ah.AccountFSID
Where 
((Month(ah.SnapshotDate) = (Month(GETDATE()) - 1) and (Year(ah.SnapshotDate) = (Year(GETDATE()))
and
Count(ah.IsBelow) < 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at one month, say January 2019. You want to find all accounts that didn't go below 500$ in that month.

In order to that, we must first find the initial value. If there is an entry of January 1, we are fine, otherwise we must look back to find the last date before then. So it's the maximum date before January 2 we are looking for.

```
select account_id
from transactions t1
where transaction_date >=
(
  select max(t2.transaction_date)
  from transactions t2
  where t2.account_id = t1.account_id
  and t2.transaction_date < '20190102'
)
and transaction_date < '20190201'
group by account_id
having min(transaction_date) >= 500;
```

Change the date literals according to the month you want to examine.